# XPATH library for extract content of element (PROLOG)

Tags: prolog

I have this code:

```
main:-
load_structure('ethernet.html',Element,[dialect(sgml),shorttag(false)]),
    xpath(Element, //title, TITLE).
```

and the result is:

```
TITLE=element(title,[],[This is my lan]).
```

I would get only "This is my lan". How can I do?
I have read [library(xpath)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=xpath/3) but i don't found solution.

Answer (score 1):

Element holds the full page structure. What are you searching into ?

For instance, to iterate over all paragraphs and display indented

```
...
forall(xpath(Element, //p, Para), xml_show("", _, Para))
...
```

where xml_show it's an helper I wrote some time ago, attempting to inspect some real world data.

```
%%  xml_show(+Depth, +ElShow, +E)
%
%   display xml tree indented
%
xml_show(Depth, ElShow, E) :-
    format('~s~@~n', [Depth, (ground(ElShow) -> call(ElShow, E) ; xml_elshow(E) )]),
    (   E = element(_, _, Xs)
    ->  !, maplist(xml_show([0' |Depth], ElShow), Xs)
    ;   true
    ).

:- meta_predicate xml_show(+, 1, +).

xml_elshow(E) :-
    E = element(D, A, _)
    -> write(D:A)
    ;  write(E).
```

Comment: I have solved my problem with "xpath(Element,//title(content),TITLE)". So i obtained TITLE = [This is my lan].

Comment: sorry, I didn't understood your question.